# Python combine function

Tags: python, one-liner

Today i'll publish a riddle.

The best answer will be the shortest code.

Write a one liner function that accepts a currency and a list of numbers. The function needs to return a **string** where each number from the list is attached with its currency.

Here's an example for a simple way to solve it.

```
def combine_coin(coin, numbers):
    coins_str = ''
    for num in numbers:
        coins_str += coin + str(num) + ', '
    return coins_str[:-2]

print(combine_coin('$', range(5)))
```

Comment: there's a site for that: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(','.join(list(map(lambda num:"$"+num,input("enter the values <sep by space>").split()))))
```

Okay splitting this long line, we get 1)
`','.join(list(` - this  will join the list we get with a comma

2)`map`- maps a function to all values in a list and returns a map object containing the return value of the function

3)`lambda num:'$'+str(num)` - takes a number and returns its string with a '$' example: '$1'

4)`input().split()`- splits the input by space

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
def combine_coin(coin, numbers):
    return ', '.join([f'{coin}{k}' for k in numbers])
```

Answer (score 0):

Codegolf is fun:

```
def combine_coin(c, n):
    return ', '.join(c+str(k) for k in n)
```

Comment: why did you accept a much longer solution then? :-)